# Probability of dense subgraph in a random graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs, random-matrices

**What is the probability that a random graph with $n$ vertices and degree sequence $\left(d_i\right)_{i=1..n}$ has a subgraph of $k$ vertices and density $\delta$?**

The random graph is typically obtained through the [configuration model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model).

The (simpler) case where the degree sequence is not prescribed but only the number $m$ of edges, leading to an [Erdős–Rényi random graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model), is also of interest.

Context: I generate random graphs and then add dense subgraphs to them in order to test an algorithm for detecting them, but I need to know if it is reasonable to assume that the initial graph has no such subgraph.